# PHP Dynamic Regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm relativly new to regular expressions but I managed to create a working expression to validate dates (without leap years, and assuming people enter a valid 30 or 31 digit for a month).

This is the expressen:
`/^\d[1-31]{2}\-\d[1-12]{2}\-\d[1900-2009]{4}$/`

But I would like to have a dynamic regular expression like:

```
$yearSpan = (date("Y") - 110)."-".date("Y");
/^\d[1-31]{2}\-\d[1-12]{2}\-\d[$yearSpan]{4}$/
```

When I try to use this expression it keeps telling me the compilation failed because a range out of order in character class.

I'm using this expression to validate dates of birth, and it would be nice not to update it every time a year passes by.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with PHP date and time functions
http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider using some date/time functions for this purpose.

You're using the character classes in wrong way. `[1-31]`, `[1-12]` and `[1900-2009]` will not check for the ranges you have in them. That's not how [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) work and hence that's not how you check for [numeric ranges](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) with regex.

A character class `[a-r]` matches any char from `a` to `r`. `[a-rx]` matches any character from `a` to `r` and the character `x`. Similarly, `[1-39]` matches any character from `1` to `3` and the character `9` - hence it matches one of 1,2,3 and 9 - and not any number from 1 to 39 as you intended it to.

`[1-31]{2}` matches two consecutive numbers (the last 1 is redundant), both in the range 1 to 3 - `33` is a valid match.

To match a number from 1 to 31, the correct regex is `0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]`. ('0?' takes care of zero padding as in `01-09-2009`

For months: `0?[1-9]|1[0-2]`

For year: `19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]`

And `-` is not a meta character outside character classes - you need not escape it.

The correct regex would be:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9])$/
```

If you are not interested in capturing the values, you can write it as:

```
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9])$/
```

Comment: Thanks for you clear answer! I'll use the checkdate function mentioned by Rimian.